# Use the Induction to Prove that.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I need ur help with this question.

The question states that: Use Induction TO Prove that

- 1*2+2*3+...+n(n+1) = n(n+1)(n+2)/3

So, so far I used to the basis step to show that this statement is indeed true.

- For n = 1, we have 1(1+1) = 1(1+1)(1+2)/3
- 2 = 2  which is true

Now the Inductive Step:

- Assume that P(n): 1*2+2*3+...+n(n+1) = n(n+1)(n+2)/3

Now from then I have no idea what to do. So can someone help me finish this unfinished question.

Thank You.

Comment: You need to assume that hypothesis is true for all numbers less than n and than reduce the case for n to the case for n-1. This will require some algebra, though. It seems like a widespread exercise, you may find dozens of similiar on the web.

Comment: Its not the same question.

Comment: @user372204 sorry, how is your question different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, next step: Proving for k+1.  Let's take $$1\cdot2+2\cdot3+....k(k+1)+(k+1)(k+2)=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}$$

Using the induction step we have... $$\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}+(k+1)(k+2)$$

Simplifying we get $$\frac{k^3+3k^2+2k}{3}+\frac{3k^2+9k+6}{3}$$
Which equals $$\frac{k^3+6k^2+11k+6}{3}$$

Factor and we have $$\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}$$

Comment: Thanx so Much ..

Answer (score 0):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1}k(k+1)=1(1+1)(1+2)/3$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)=n(n+1)(n+2)/3$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}k(k+1)=$

$\color\red{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)}+(n+1)(n+2)=$

$\color\red{n(n+1)(n+2)/3}+(n+1)(n+2)=$

$(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/3$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: Thanxxxxx for this

Comment: @user372204: You're welcome :)